# Listing file in Haxe with the Windows (cpp) target returns empty strings?

Tags: haxe, openfl

I am listing files with Haxe on cpp Windows using:

```
FileSystem.readDirectory('\some\path\here');
```

I get back an array of empty strings.
Interestingly the number of strings I get back matches the file count.

Answer (score 1):

The installation for haxe 3.4.4 appears to come by default with hxcpp 4.0.19 which works some of the time but with some issues. I had to downgrade and switch to hxcpp 3.4.188.

```
haxelib install hxcpp 3.4.188
haxelib set hxcpp 3.4.188
```

Then it worked perfectly.

Comment: I think there's a good chance this is the same issue as https://github.com/openfl/lime/issues/1331, in which case installing hxcpp from GitHub instead should work as well (and releases after 4.0.19 wouldn't have this issue anymore).